# HTML Make code run independently from the rest of the page...iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

This is a little hard to explain.  I'm creating a webpage that shows how other webpages will render in the browser. Here's a simplified version of the problem I'm having...

```
<div id="test">This is an example of page 1</div>

<div id="test">This is an example of page 2</div>
```

As you can see, both divs have the same ID.  I can't change the ID in my situation and it's causing problems.  I'm having various other CSS and javascript problems also. Each section of code is conflicting with the other. So, I was looking for a way to have a section render independently of everything else.  One way to do it would be to create an iframe for each section of code.  But that would require me to create a separate webpage for each section, right?  Or, is there a way for an iframe to work just by entering code into it, rather than a URL.

Comment: This was solved by Tiffany.  Using the srcdoc feature of iframes did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one id per element in an HTML document.  So each div must have a different id, otherwise you *will* run into problems.  If multiple elements need to have the same name, you can use classes `<div class="test" id="unique-id"></div>` and then `<div class="test" id="another-id"></div>`.

To answer your question with regards to iframes, yes, you need a separate page for each iframe.  It is not possible to write code within the iframe tags to execute separately.  See the [iframe spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-iframe-element).

Edit: After reading the iframe spec myself, it appears you can use the `srcdoc` attribute to overwrite what is in the `src` attribute, but it looks like [this isn't entirely accepted across browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcdoc).  [MDN has more information about the attribute.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as I said, it can be done with iframes.  I was looking for a way to do it without creating a separate iframe page.  I can't use classes in my situation.  one reason is because I am using <label for   in my html.   The "for" requires an ID.  a class won't work.    It's hard to explain why I can't change the IDs to something different for each one, but lets just say I can't.

Comment: If you need to target labels with CSS, do you know about ```input[for="someInput"]{ /* CSS here */ }```?

Comment: That sounds insteresting.  I will look into that.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored Check out [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).  Also note that they're a bit lower on the specificity chart, and will get overwritten by CSS that select against id or classes.

Comment: This srcdoc thing you mentioned sounds like what I need.  I'm looking for more info on that.

Comment: WE HAVE A WINNER !   Thank you very much   I can make this work with srcdoc.

Comment: Just be aware that Internet Explorer and Edge don't currently support it.